# Replacement for $.ajax() in Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, http

I have been using jQuery's $.ajax() functionality to make asynchronous http requests from my Node server to other external API servers.

I now want to upgrade my libraries but I'm getting

```
....
/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level1/core.js:418
   set nodeName() { throw new core.DOMException();},
               ^^

SyntaxError: Setter must have exactly one formal parameter.
```

1. How can I fix this error?
2. Is there any library that is equally flexible as `$.ajax()` is? I'm particularly interested in the *promise* and *$.ajaxPrefilter()* functionalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, node has a module called `request` that can do a lot more than you're probably used to with `$.ajax`.  Basic example from their page:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
  }
})
```

https://github.com/request/request

As far as promises go, you can promisify anything you want with a library like bluebird: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html

jQuery on the server is wholly unnecessary -- just tear the bandaid off quickly and it'll hurt less :)

**Edit**

Adding defaults is very easy.  Just do

```
var req = request.defaults({
  token: myToken,
  ...
})

var payload = { ... }

req.get(payload, function(err, res, body){ 
  ... 
})
```

Comment: Thanks tyler. I checked `request` but I couldn't find a way to add a prefilter to it. Do you have any ideas on that? I basically want to add a token to every request made.

Comment: They call them defaults, not prefilter.  I've added an example above.

Comment: should it be request.defaults({qs: {token: myToken}}) ?

Comment: Depends on your auth scheme.  I use `request.defaults({ auth: { bearer: myToken } })`, but you can do it however you want.

Comment: request is deprecated and I don't find a clear alternative...